# Elasticsearch and Spring Data: how to reindex with alias

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a bean annotated as such:

```
@Document(indexName = "foo", type = "bar")
public class BarEntity {
    private String someField = "";
}
```

"foo" is an alias in elasticsearch to foo-2016-11-04:

```
"foo-2016.11.04" : {
  "aliases" : {
    "foo" : { }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is change someField's indexing to not_analyzed:

```
@Document(indexName = "foo", type = "bar")
public class BarEntity {
    @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String someField = "";
}
```

As far as I can tell, I'll have to create a new index and point the alias to that, e.g. foo-2016.11.29.
How can I do this in elasticeseach 2.3 with Spring Data?
My bean is linked to the alias, and Spring Data would create the correct index automatically I guess.
I just don't know how to make it create the index via an alias.
Do I first reindex foo-2016.11.04 to foo-2016.11.29, update the alias to point to the new one and just redeploy the spring app, or is there something else to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create index through alias, but you can create your timestamped index explicitly and assign it to an alias automatically using index template.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-templates.html

Comment: by creating the index explicitly, do you mean assign the bean to a timestamped index? like so: @Document(indexName = "foo-2016.11.29", type = "bar")

Comment: probably, I've explained how it works on the level of ES API, if something is not possible there, spring-data will not help you. 
IMHO, spring-data-es offers totally wrong approach to using ES.

Comment: thanks. so basically, I'd change @ Document to point to a newly timestamped index in order to create it with the updated definition, then change the alias to point to the newly created index, then change the @ Document back to point to the alias, and finally do the reindexing. wow... alright, will give it a shot, but like you said, it definitely sounds weird.

Comment: if you have created index template (not ElasticsearchTemplate class, but using rest api) with appropriate wildcard it will handle alias assignment for all new indices matching the wildcard. Still you have to delete old index or unassign it from the alias.

Comment: great, thanks, so what i'll do is: 1. create new index via curl 2. point the existing alias to it 3. relaunch docker w/ spring data-enabled pojo classes 4. spring data will take care of the mapping.